# Slow Performance 16.04LTS

Tags: performance

Today I installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my laptop.

I realized that even without having anything installed and my apt already updated, it features slow and loud noise coming from the hard drive, like it very difficult to function properly.

In others linux distributions or other operational systems, this problems doesn't happen.

The configuration of my laptop this:

- Intel Dual Core
- 2GB RAM

Please, help me.

Comment: You could check if you are already using the "right" graphic driver - by opening the 'Additional Drivers' dialog. In some cases that might help - assuming its the graphic card producing  fan noise right now

Comment: you could check if something is very active on disk. you can use diskio or dstat -D hda as recommended here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskPerformance